# How can I determine what org edition I have

Tags: partner-portal

This might sound like a foolish question, but as a partner I can spin up a test org for any Salesforce edition. I have a few still with the @[number]demo.com username, and I'm trying to identify which edition they are.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Log in to the org, its part of the page title, e.g. "salesforce.com - Developer Edition"

Comment: my tabs were not wide enough :)

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a user script to [show the org name](http://bit.ly/POfbrW) in the messages section at the top right of pages.  You could modify it to query `Organization.OrganizationType`.

Comment: Thank you for showing how to do this programatically, it's been a big help.