# Checking your type of Org

Tags: managed-package, beta-managed-package, org

I am trying to create a beta managed package.

According to this: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/How_to_Create_and_Register_a_Package#Unmanaged_vs._Managed

```
ONLY Developer Edition can create Managed Packages
```

I cannot create a managed package.  I want to check my Org is developer edition (as I thought it was).  I go to set up / company profile / company information.

But I cannot see what "type" of org this is from this page. Any tips?

Note: I don't always see the org name when I log in, on top of page.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2106/how-can-i-determine-what-org-edition-i-have                                       look the previous post and tell me if you happy so that i can close this question

Comment: @Mohith Kumar - I don't always see this. I have updated question with picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Hover the tab of the browser and you will see whats the edition .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OrganizationType field on Organization to find Org Type:

> system.debug([SELECT OrganizationType FROM Organization]);

For more details visit https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/84962/352